# What are the differences between PySAL and spatstat?

Tags: python, r, spatstat, pysal

I've been working with spatstat in R for quite a while now and am curious what the big differences between the packages (PySAL in python and spatstat in R) are functionality-wise. Is either more potent or faster, does one have more pre-set functions?
Thanks loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an appropriate question for this forum.

However, the main differences between the two packages can be seen by reading their documentation: `spatstat` is designed for analysing spatial point patterns, is written by statisticians following statistical principles and conventions, contains current techniques from the statistical literature, and does not handle file input/output directly. `PySAL` is designed for spatial data in general (with relatively less functionality for spatial point patterns), is written by geographers, and includes capabilities for reading spatial data file formats.